# SyntaxError : Missing : after property id

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a simple algorithm that can solve a simple math calculation. I made a variable 'operator' which is an array that contains *, /, +, and -

```
var operator = {"*", "/", "+", "-*};
```

I am getting this error "missing : after property id"

Comment: I know its weird make that four operators in array, but i dont know how to makena looping that each calculation have different operator from all possibility

Comment: can you add in more code around how are you trying to use this variable?

Comment: _"its an array"_ - An array is `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the curly braces to square brackets

e.g.

```
var operator = ["*", "/", "+", "-"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the closing `"` in minus operator and u are declaring an object not an array.

```
var operator = {"*", "/", "+", "-"};

var operator = ["*", "/", "+", "-"];
```

Comment: Each operator {each oeprator{each operator{a operator[i] b operator[j] c operator[k] d}}}

Comment: And a b c d combination was 24, i want the loop operate it, but its just display it without calculate it

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Create Array in JavaScript This Way. in JavaScript unlike C or C++ Programming Languages for Direct initialization we Sue `[` instead of `{`

Checkout MDN official Docs [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)